# Как вывести определенную часть файла?

Tags: c++, c

Пишу несложную базу данных (использую просто .txt файлы) на c++
Вот так выглядят данные в файле

- 0 //ID
- Название
- Дата
- (И еще строка с информацией)

Пользователь вводит *название* и по названию программа должна выдать всю информацию, которая принадлежит именно этому объекту в бд, кроме айди
то есть
На выходе должно быть

- Название
- Дата
- (И еще строка с информацией)

Comment: Раз вы не используете никакой системы индексации - просто читать по очереди все записи, сравнивать, выводить нужные...

Comment: Самое разумное ИМХО взять для этих целей SQlite, у вашего подхода тьма недостатков, убрать которые невозможно по причине выбранной архитектуры хранения данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут все просто берешь запускаешь for по строкам и ищешь совпадение и потом просто выводишь эту строку кроме ID(можешь просто по разделителю определить что это ID или регулярные выражения). Так же лучше не городить велосипед, и взять за основу существующую БД, кстати чтоб ускорить поиск можно строки сортировать по ID после добавления, также как Set в STL а потом бин.поиском находить строку(поиск будет работать за O(log2 N) где n это количество строк, добавление хз от реализации зависит) или хэш таблицы тоже вариант для ускорения добавления/поиска